# Where is the Radio feature in my Windows Phone 8.1(Nokia Lumia 525)?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-525, radio

Today I upgraded my Windows OS from 8 to 8.1 in my Lumia 525. Everything is looking good except some options. Main among them is hearing Music through **Radio** facility. In Windows 8.0  I was easily able to get Radio feature inside *Music and Video* but in Windows 8.1 I didn’t find that Radio inside *Music*. Inside Music I only find artists, albums, songs, genres, playlists and Radio is not there. I searched through my mobile and I didn’t find it. Can anyone tell me where it is?

Comment: Do you see FM Radio in the app list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the Radio option doesn't show up in the Music app (it does on my 920), but try checking the app list for FM Radio, it should show up there.